# Syslog filter to own file by tag or text contain

Tags: python, log-files, syslog, rsyslog

I need to log from my Python application to syslog. In syslog I want filter messages from my app to own file. I'm using Debian 8.3.

My **rsyslog** rules:

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/99-MyLog.conf 
:syslogtag, isequal, "MyLog" /var/log/mylog.log

:msg, contains, "MyLog" /var/log/mylog.log
```

And my python script */tmp/test.py*:

```
import logging.handlers

my_logger = logging.getLogger('MyLog')
my_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address = '/dev/log')
formatter = logging.Formatter('MyLog: %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
my_logger.addHandler(handler)

my_logger.info("Test Log 123")
```

If send messages to syslog:

```
# logger -t MyLog "Test from bash logger"
# logger "MyLog Test from bash logger"
# python /tmp/test.py
```

Filter works only for logger command without tag:

```
# tail -n 3 /var/log/syslog
Jun 30 09:45:42 server MyLog: Test from bash logger
Jun 30 09:45:44 server martin: MyLog Test from bash logger
Jun 30 09:45:47 server MyLog: Test Log 123

# cat /var/log/mylog.log 
Jun 30 09:45:44 server martin: MyLog Test from bash logger
```

What I do bad? I do not want filter by process name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the : in your tag in the rsyslog configuration.  Try the following:

```
:syslogtag, isequal, "MyLog:" /var/log/mylog.log
```